# Unbalanced calls and missing root view controller errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2

This is my basic storyboard layout

```
 MY MAIN Navigation Controller 
if ( abc )
--Push Segue-> [Series of View Controllers] -Modal Segue-> My ViewContrller 
else
-- Modal Segue->  My ViewContrller
```

I get these  warnings.

```
 Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

What should I DO TO Avoid them

```
NSLog(@"%@" , self.window.rootViewController.self); gives me <UINavigationController: 0x7435610>
```

Comment: For the first error, you need to assign a view controller to the window's root view controller property inside your application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.  (I don't have an answer for the second error.)

Comment: @PhillipMills its already assigned. I am using storyboards. i dont think you need coding to do that.

Comment: Do you have something assigned as the initial controller in your storyboard?  Does it load correctly?  (I ask because the app doesn't agree that it's assigned.  If you log `self.window.rootViewController` in the app delegate's `didFinish...` method, I wonder what it shows.)

Comment: Yes i have initial view controller that is my First navigation Controller. Let me check Log. Regarding second error. I fixed it by removing second navigation controller and placing only a viewController instead

Comment: NSLog(@"%@" , self.window.rootViewController.self); gives me <UINavigationController: 0x7435610>

Answer (score 0):

assign a root view to your nav controller outside of your if else, the compiler is never sure if you actually get something valid back inside of the if/else even though you always should it just never looks, i think because of the way if/else are compiled. or declare a pointer to null outside of the if/else then assign the pointer to the location of the result of your if else.

[image]

Comment: do you get the error at compile time or run time, yes at runtime everything is great, but you get the warnings at compile time or no?

Comment: ahh then ignore my answer, i was thinking this was a compile time error. Still it looks as if this is being cause by not having a rootview defined when the nav controller is instantiated. Usually you will instanciate a nav controller like: [UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:[[UIView alloc] init]];

Comment: Do you have the root view outlet hooked up in your SB?

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of your story board?

Comment: funny thing is, the bug dont show up if i use the first approach. means where i am using if (abc\)

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate class, you should be initializing a UIWindow, probably UIWindow *window

Before the `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` line, you should set `window.rootViewController = MAIN_VIEW_HERE;`

Comment: NSLog(@"%@" , self.window.rootViewController.self); gives me <UINavigationController: 0x7435610> ... I Am using storyboard not nibs so I can't name nibs.